# Prove rigorously on $[0, \delta]$ that $\frac{f(x)}{\sin{x}}$ is integrable iff $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm reviewing a textbook, and in one proof, they use the fact that since $\sin{x}$ approximates $g(x) = x$ on $[0, \delta]$ for small $\delta$, we get the following relation:

$$\displaystyle \int \limits_{0}^{\delta} \left |\frac{f(x)}{\sin{x}} \right |\,dx < \infty \text{ iff }\int \limits_{0}^{\delta}\left | \frac{f(x)}{x} \right | \,dx < \infty$$

If this is true, how would I rigorously prove it?

Comment: Here "integrable" means Riemann-integrable or Lebesgue-integrable?

Comment: Note that if $\delta<\pi$, there are finite constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $c_1\frac{f(x)}x < \frac{f(x)}{\sin x} < c_2\frac{f(x)}{x}$ on $(0,\delta)$.

Comment: Also, $\frac{1}{\sin z} - \frac{1}{z}$ is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $0$, in particular continuous (and bounded) on $\{ z : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant \pi/2\}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I just mean is the integral finite.  We could go with Lebesgue (though I'm not sure why it matters -- please let me know why it matters which integrable I mean so I understand).

Comment: @user46944: about Lebesgue integrability, we have that $\left|\frac{f(x)}{\sin x}\right|$ is bounded from above *and* from below by some constant times $\left|\frac{f(x)}{x}\right|$. The same argument with the Riemann integral is a bit more delicate since we have to properly deal with $f(x)$ being negative.

Comment: For instance, consider $\frac{\sin(\tan x)}{\sin x\cos x}$ over $I=[0,\pi/2)$. It is a (improperly) Riemann-integrable function over $I$, and not a Lebesgue integrable function over $I$. To prove that the same happens for $\frac{\sin(\tan x)}{x\cos x}$ is not exactly trivial.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Wow, I was always under the assumption that if a function is Riemann integrable, it is Lebesgue integrable and their integrals are equal.  I guess this could fail if the function is improperly Riemann integrable as your example shows.

Comment: @user46944: That is true only over compact sets or for non-negative functions. $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is improperly Riemann integrable over $\mathbb{R}^+$, but for sure is not a $L^1(\mathbb{R}^+)$ function. Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: ... Is $f\ge 0$?

Comment: Well then what is $< \infty$ all about?

Comment: @zhw. Corrected.

Comment: Ok, the new version with absolute values has no delicate part.

Comment: Just use $(2/\pi)x < \sin x < x, 0<x<\pi/2$ then.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Sorry for being sloppy.

Comment: @zhw. That's robjohn's hint.  I'm trying to prove it now so I can use it.

Comment: Note that because $\sin x /x \to 1$ we have $1/2 < \sin x/x < 3/2$ for $x$ in some $(0,\delta).$

Comment: @zhw. Thank you for the great note/hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** for $|x|\le\frac\pi2$, show that
$$
\left|\frac{2x}\pi\right|\le|\sin(x)|\le|x|
$$

Comment: Do I *have* to show it for $|x| < \frac{\pi}{2}$?  I can't do it.  Based on zhw.'s great hint above, I can show it for some $\delta$, but there's no guarantee that $\delta > \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: The inequality is true for $|x|\le\frac\pi2$. You can use it on any smaller interval.